# Custom Payment Method Error - Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I need to develop a custom payment method (for magento 1.9). I have followed the instructions from [this](http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/) site. The payment method appears in the checkout page. However when i click the place order button i'm getting following error.

```
Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46
```

It seems that other people are also facing the same error. It looks like that following observer is called before calling the response action of my payment method.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php
```

The following code not able to get the payment method associated with the order.

```
$order->getPayment()
```

The error is generating even before reaching the response action function. I have also added the logic to retrieve the orderId in the response action page. But since the error generated before reaching this function, this is something related to config or in payment method code. I believe that i must be missing something in the config or in the payment method code. Can any one please help me debug this error. I have verified some existing payment methods and added following set codes in the Model.

```
    protected $_code = 'eazypay';
    protected $_isGateway = false;
    protected $_canAuthorize = false;
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
    protected $_canRefund = false;
    protected $_canVoid = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal = false;
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
    protected $_paymentMethod = 'standard';
    protected $_order;
```

I thought adding `protected $_paymentMethod = 'standard';` might resolve the issue. But still i'm getting error.

Please see the code in Model:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Eazypay_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    protected $_code = 'eazypay';
    protected $_isGateway = false;
    protected $_canAuthorize = false;
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
    protected $_canRefund = false;
    protected $_canVoid = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal = false;
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
    protected $_paymentMethod = 'standard';
    protected $_order;

    public function cleanString($string)
    {

        $string_step1 = strip_tags($string);
        $string_step2 = nl2br($string_step1);
        $string_step3 = str_replace("<br />", "<br>", $string_step2);
        $cleaned_string = str_replace("\"", " inch", $string_step3);
        return $cleaned_string;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkout session namespace
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Session
     */
    public function getCheckout()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

    /**
     * Get current quote
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    public function getQuote()
    {
        return $this->getCheckout()->getQuote();
    }

    /**
     * Get order model
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {

        if (!$this->_order) {
            $paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
            $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->loadByIncrementId($paymentInfo->getOrder()->getRealOrderId());
        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('eazypay/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
    }

    public function getShippingAddress($order)
    {
        $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $addr_entity_id = $shipping->getCustomerAddressId();
        $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
        return $shippingaddress->load($addr_entity_id);
    }

    public function getRedirectURL()
    {

        $success = 'onepage/success/';
        $coFields = array();
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getRealOrderId();
        $shippingAddress = $this->getShippingAddress($order);
        $phone = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
        $grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
        $paymode = 9;
        $redirectURL = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/payment/eazypay/api_url');

        $merchantid = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/eazypay/merchantid', Mage::app()->getStore());
        $key = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/eazypay/key', Mage::app()->getStore());
        $referenceNum = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/eazypay/reference_num', Mage::app()->getStore());
        $submerchantid = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/eazypay/submerchant_id', Mage::app()->getStore());
        $debug_mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/eazypay/debug_mode');

        $coFields['merchantid'] = $merchantid;
        $mandatoryfields = "$referenceNum|$submerchantid|$grandTotal|test|$phone";
        $returnurl = 'http://localhost/buildnext/index.php/eazypay/payment/response/?';//Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).$success;
        $returnURL_params = "ReferenceNo=$orderId&submerchantid=$submerchantid&ransaction amount=$grandTotal&paymode=$paymode";
        $returnurl .= $returnURL_params;

        if ($debug_mode) {
            $debugModel = Mage::getModel('eazypay/eazypaydebug');
            $debugModel->setOrderId($orderId);
            $debugModel->setParams($mandatoryfields);
            $debugModel->setCreatedDatetime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            $debugModel->save();
        }

        $en_mandatoryfields = $this->aes128Encrypt($mandatoryfields, $key);
        $en_returnurl = $this->aes128Encrypt($returnurl, $key);
        $en_referencenum = $this->aes128Encrypt($referenceNum, $key);
        $en_submerchantid = $this->aes128Encrypt($submerchantid, $key);
        $en_transaction_amount = $this->aes128Encrypt(1, $key);
        $en_paymode = $this->aes128Encrypt($paymode, $key);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEazyPayOrdId($orderId);

        $redirectURL = "merchantid=$merchantid"
            . "&mandatory fields=$en_mandatoryfields"
            . "&optional fields="
            . "&returnurl=$en_returnurl"
            . "&Reference No=$en_referencenum"
            . "&submerchantid=$en_submerchantid&transaction amount=$en_transaction_amount"
            . "&paymode=$en_paymode";
        return $redirectURL;
    }

    function aes128Encrypt($str, $key)
    {
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael_128', 'ecb');
        $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
}

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**:
Please note that 'Standard' is the name of the model class

---

**EDIT**:
Adding `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Buildnext_Eazypay>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Buildnext_Eazypay>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eazypay>
                <class>Buildnext_Eazypay_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>eazypay_resource</resourceModel>
            </eazypay>
            <eazypay_resource>
                <class>Buildnext_Eazypay_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <eazypaydebug>
                        <table>eazypay_debug</table>
                    </eazypaydebug>
                </entities>
            </eazypay_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <eazypay>
                <class>Buildnext_Eazypay_Helper</class>
            </eazypay>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <eazypay>
                <class>Buildnext_Eazypay_Block</class>
            </eazypay>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <eazypay_standard>
                <model>eazypay/standard</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>ICICI Eazypay</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <api_url>https://eazypay.icicibank.com/EazyPG?</api_url>
            </eazypay_standard>
        </payment>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <eazypay>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Buildnext_Eazypay</module>
                    <frontName>eazypay</frontName>
                </args>
            </eazypay>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: can you share your `config.xml` file?

Comment: Added config.xml